# Как сделать приложения на latex с кириллической нумерацией по центру?

Tags: latex

Требуется сделать в latex-документе приложения такого вида:
[image: вид приложений]

Буксую уже на стадии кириллической нумерации:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Asbuk\c@section}}
\makeatother
```

не даёт никакого результата и постоянно выводит `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{section.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`. Использование вместо `\@Asbuk` других наборов символов работает (правда, формируются неправильные ссылки).

Документ имеет класс `extarticle`.

Может, есть какие-то готовые рецепты? Если нет, то подскажите мне, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать.

Comment: если вы бы приложили минимальный достаточный пример, ответить было бы проще.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну, минимальным достаточным примером должно быть что-то работающее, верно? А так здесь вроде есть код переопределения счётчика (который не работает) и то, что мне нужно сделать. Что ещё надо?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, извините, но я всё-таки так и не пойму, что ещё мне следует добавить.

Comment: пример должен быть рабочим. чтобы можно было скопировать его, запустить, и получить нечто работоспособное. в ответе я привёл минимальный достаточный пример.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, теперь понял. Так и написали бы, "добавьте преамбулу" )

Comment: не просто «преамбулу», а всё, что необходимо для **компиляции** программы (ведь *tex* — это же (почти) полноценный язык программирования).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. изменить нумерацию разделов/секций (*sections*) можно, переопределив команду `\thesection`:

   ```
   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Asbuk{section}}
   ```
2. изменить заголовок раздела/секции (*section*) можно, например, с помощью пакета [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), используя входящую в него команду `\titleformat`.

так как вам нужно переопределять заголовки приложений (*appendices*), то, соответственно, обе этих команды нужно вставить уже после команды `\appendix`.

[наглядная демонстрация](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bvkjndgwczst). код:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\title{пример с приложениями}
\begin{document}
\section{раз}
текст
\section{два}
текст
\appendix
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\centering Приложение\ \thesection\\(справочное)}
  {0pt}{\Large\centering}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Asbuk{section}}

\section{приложение раз}
текст
\section{приложение два}
текст
\end{document}
```

картинкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]